# Stop macro if column is blank excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have made some code but if the range R2:34 is blank, it will still open the template email with no data in him. Please tell me where am I doing the bad connection.

```
Sub 1()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sTo As String
    Dim spo As String
    Dim emailRng As Range, cl As Range, dtrecuta As Range
    Dim c As Range
For Each cell In Cells.Range("N2:N34")
If LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "N").Value) = "0" Or LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "N").Value) < "480" Then
On Error Resume Next
Cells(cell.Row, "R").Value = Cells(cell.Row, "M").Value
Else
Cells(cell.Row, "R").Value = Null
End If
Next cell
    a = CLng(Date)
    Set emailRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("r2:r34")
    Set dtrecuta = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("P2")
    For Each cl In emailRng
        sTo = sTo & ";" & cl.Value
    Next
    sTo = Mid(sTo, 2)
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\Marius\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\statistica.oft")
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = sTo
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "TESTARE Statistica pentru data de " & dtrecuta
        strbody = "Buna " & " , " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                  "Te rog sa trimiti statistica astazi " & a & " pana in ora 10:00, " & _
                  " pentru data de " & dtrecuta & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "O zi buna." & _
                  " " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & " Acesta este un mesaj automat nu raspundeti la acest e-mail. "
        .Display
        .Body = strbody & Signature
        .send
    End With
            On Error GoTo cleanup
            Set OutMail = Nothing
cleanup:
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want the macro to stop, when a column is blank? Or it *is* stopping, and you don't want it to?

Comment: Hi, I just want to stop because if range r2:r34 is blank, the code is void. If there is data in range r2:r34 is ok to go on with the code but must stop if range is empty . Column R depends on column N, that depends on another sheet.

Comment: Would adding `If Len(sTo)=<32 Then Exit Sub` before the `sTo = Mid(sTo, 2)` line of code resolve this? so that if the recipients list (sTo) is just 32 semi-colons it will exit the sub?

Comment: Hi, adding <= 32 does not work. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an IF statement just after setting your range to check if it is all blank cells:

```
Set emailRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("r2:r34")
If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(emailRng) = emailRng.Cells.Count Then Exit Sub  'No data
```