# Do not run paste macro if all cells in a column are empty

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that looks for records in Column B and if there is a value in a cell within that column then the macro will add a value to Column A in the same row. My problem occurs when Column B has NO values in it whatsoever. The macro just continues running endlessly in those instances. What I am looking for is a way to say:

- If Column B contains NO value then skip to the next macro.

I know this involves an IF statement of some kind I just can not figure out how to add that logic into my existing code.

My code:

```
Sub Update_Column_Based_On_Column_Value_1()
On Error Resume Next
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1:A" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=If(LEN(RC2),""NEW VALUE GOES HERE"", TEXT(,))"
        .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value = .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

My search for the answer yielded this string of code from another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880797/stop-macro-if-column-is-blank-excel-vba):

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(emailRng) = emailRng.Cells.Count Then Exit Sub  'No data
```

When I added that to my code it simply ended the sub if there were ANY blank cells in a column.

Thanks in advance for the assistance! I do apologize if my question is overly noobish.

Comment: The Range `emailRng` is not defined in your code.

Comment: Next macro? you mean to say it should skip the row or the macro should stop?

Comment: So the range I would need to add is (B2:B) and then swap that in for emailRng?

Comment: I mean it should stop the macro if the range is empty @nishit dey

Comment: Use `Set emailRng = .Range("B2:B" & lRow)` within your `With` block.

Comment: So it will look like this:
`lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'The column in "" must change to match the target column
Set testRng = Worksheets("Data").Range("B2:B")
If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(testRng) = testRng.Cells.Count Then Exit Sub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Update_Column_Based_On_Column_Value_1()
On Error Resume Next
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ' This will count all non-blanks in Column B, I put equal to 1
    ' because I am assuming B1 is a header with a title so it will at minimum be 1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("B:B")) = 1 Then
        ' if count is equal to 1 then this part will run
        ' so enter name of the sub() or write new code in here
    Else
        ' if not less than or equal, meaning greater than 1
        ' then the following code below will run
        With ws
            lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range("A1:A" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=If(LEN(RC2),""NEW VALUE GOES HERE"", TEXT(,))"
            .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value = .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value
        End With
    End If
```

Comment: Hey @fcsr,

Where exactly would this fit into the rest of the code I have above? Thank you for the assistance, your post was very clear.

Comment: sorry wait, i have to edit this, if range is blank then it will throw an error. You could use `on error goto` but I want to find a more elegant approach.

Comment: Sorry about the delayed response but the answer provided by Jerry actually solved another problem I had. But your solution totally solved the one that this question was made for! Did you make your edit? It appears that you did as what you provided above worked on a blank range. Exactly how I needed it to!

Comment: Yup edited it, took a different route as my original answer was troublesome. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

This code will do what you want

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long
Dim lRow As Long

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lRow
        If Cells(i, "B").Value <> vbNullString Then
            Cells(i, "A").Value = Cells(i, "B").Value
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What can I say Jerry this works perfectly! I even needed to run this on multiple columns after Column B and this code doesn't overwrite any of that Column A data when I do that.

Comment: Thanks, i glad it helped.